# Bootstrap4 -- fullscreen dashboard with images that resize and fill/stretch into their divs?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, fullscreen, responsive-images

Been trying to get this working for a couple of days now without any luck.

This is dedicated for a larger monitor (2560x1080).. so lower viewport responsiveness doesnt matter.

I'm trying to:

1. Make container fit large full screen edge to edge.
2. Create a grid (i.e. like the one in attached image)
3. Display images in that grid cells that use exactly 100% of the space available to them (based on the % values of the underlying cell/div) -- so resize with aspect ratio and then stretch or something like that.

Unfortunately every attempt is just a mess... most recently I'm using bootstrap 4 with the following extra css

https://codepen.io/jpub/pen/qBNbGOV

```
#mmenu_screen > .row {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
    .flex-fill {
    flex:1 1 auto;
}
```

Any tips would be appreciated.

**It should look like this.......**

[image: *** EXAMPLE TARGET LAYOUT IMAGE ***]

Comment: Please revise to explain exactly what you're having trouble with. It's not clear from either this post or your demo (you might reduce its size since most of us don't have a huge monitor available).

Comment: [...since most of us don't have a huge monitor available]



That's the problem (what this post is about.) We don't either. Not that big anyway. The images do not scale. If I change the size of the placeholder images, it defeats the purpose of the problem.

Comment: @isherwood maybe this helps so people can see it better:

https://codepen.io/jpub/pen/RwRabaY

all I did for this fork was reduce the height of the images and change them all to img-fluid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no bootstrap or framework needed CSS grid got you covered ;) it's a simple API read the CSS and you will understand how does it work you just add the needed divs then you give it literally a template and he will arrange them for you it's 100% responsive (to the limit for sure of the content).

- to control the images use a background image and size with percentage with "background-size"  ;)

hope I have helped

```css
.grid-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'area1 area1 area1 area1 area4 area4'
    'area1 area1 area1 area1 area5 area5'
    'area2 area2 area3 area3 area6 area6'
    'area2 area2 area3 area3 area7 area7';
  grid-gap: 10px;
  
  background-color: #f9fad2;
  padding: 10px;

}

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: #18bc9c;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}



.item1 { grid-area: area1;  background-image: url("https://www.bmw.in/content/dam/bmw/marketIN/bmw_in/Images/all-models/BMW%20Series/bmw-2-series/Main%20Banner%20Desktop.jpg/_jcr_content/renditions/cq5dam.resized.img.1680.large.time1601620546255.jpg");  background-size: cover;  }
.item2 { grid-area: area2; }
.item3 { grid-area: area3; }
.item4 { grid-area: area4; }
.item5 { grid-area: area5; }
.item6 { grid-area: area6;  }
.item7 { grid-area: area7;  background-image: url("https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/190815154638-01-bugatti-centodieci-exlarge-169.jpg");    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%; }
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>  
  <div class="item4">4</div>
  <div class="item5">5</div>
   <div class="item6">6</div>
  <div class="item7">7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly - and so simple!  Thank you!

Comment: Also grid-template-areas is awesome. Wow. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/#prop-grid-template-areas   Btw, I am doing this to make a kiosk style display screen for our video cameras. Our current system has lots of problems, so I thought I would make a direct-camera-access view and set up chrome in kiosk mode so when power is lost and restored, the screen comes back up to this view.